# will access token expires after changing redirect uri in oauth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on Oauth2 implementation 
I have gone through all the process of generating  authorisation code, access token and refresh code generation and it is working fine now.

I have a doubt in such a situation,

I already have an active access token and it is decided to change redirect uri,

> after the change of redirect uri will i expires my access token or can
>   i use the active access token after the change in redirect uri

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: That will be up to the service, the spec has nothing to say about this. Best off asking them :P If it were my implementation, I would nuke the tokens on `redirect_uri` change

Comment: ok, thank you for your time.